# Classic parallel clustering algorithms

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, dc.parallel-comp, clustering

I'm starting a research about parallel clustering. I see a ton of articles on this topic, so that I don't know where to start. I'd like to get familiar with classic methods of parallelizing clustering. Are there any "have-to-know" books/papers in this area, that would provide me a good introduction?

I'm interested in shared-nothing architecture, generally something that may be suitable for map-reduce model.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf_cluster

Answer (score 3):

There's been recent work on doing clustering in the MRC model (a formal model for analyzing mapreduce computations). Specifically, you should look at the work by [Bahmani et al](http://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/papers/vldb12-kmpar.pdf) in VLDB 2012 on k-means$||$ and earlier work by [Ene et al](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2020408.2020515) in KDD 2011 on the same topic. These papers have some discussion of the general problem of parallelizing $k$-means, which might be a good jumping off point for what you're interested in.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested to [this survey](http://www.cs.gsu.edu/~wkim/index_files/SurveyParallelClustering.pdf) done by a Ph.D. student, which is updated to 2009 and presents classical work on parallel clustering. The survey is full of references you may then read to delve into the gory details.